# How to add items to favorite activity with SQLite database in android programming

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have navigationdrawer with nav menu .When click on each item navigation drawer, one fragment loaded. Inside each fragment I load data from External SQLite database,  and show with Recyclerview. Now I want add favorite button for when click on it, item added to favorited item and background favorite button must be changed to liked. Or when click on favorited item, item UnFavorited and background changed to UnLiked button. I CREATE "Favorite" column in the table, and intiallized each raw to 0 = text, because when app loaded for first , nothing items isn't favorite. Now I don't how done this function. Please help me.

this is my **WorldCOuntryDabase**

```
public class WorldCountryDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "databaseHelper";
private static final String DB_NAME = "worldCountries.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "country";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase database;


public WorldCountryDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

    File file = new File(DB_PATH + "worldCountries.db");
    if (file.exists())

        openDataBase();

    this.mContext = context;


}

public void createDatabase() {

    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

    if (dbExist) {

        Log.d("MIN1", "Database already Exist");

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    try {
        copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("MIN2", e.getMessage());

    }


}

private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {


        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("MIN3", e.getMessage());

    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
        SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
    }
    super.close();

}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    try {


        InputStream in = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }


        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

        Log.d("MIN4", "Database copy");


    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d("MIN5", e.getMessage());

    }
}

public Cursor QueryData(String query) {
    return database.rawQuery(query, null);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    Log.d("MIN6", "onCreate");



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {




    Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Upgrading Database from version" + oldVersion + "To" + newVersion +
            "Which will destroy all  oldest data");


    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public void openDataBase() {

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Log.d("MIN7", "Opened database");


}

// CRUD Table
public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {

    List<Questions> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY Random()", null);
        if (c == null) return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String Image = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
            String AnswerA = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerA"));
            String AnswerB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerB"));
            String AnswerC = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerC"));
            String AnswerD = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AnswerD"));
            String CorrectAnswer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CorrectAnswer"));

            Questions question = new Questions(Id, Image, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD, CorrectAnswer);
            questionsList.add(question);


        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    database.close();
    return questionsList;
}


// Insert Score to Ranking table.
public void insertScore(double score) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put("Score", score);
    db.insert("Ranking", null, content);
}

// Get score and sort Ranking.
public List<Ranking> getRanking() {

    List<Ranking> rankingList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Ranking ORDER BY Score DESC;", null);
        if (c == null) return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {

            int Id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"));
            int Score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Score"));

            Ranking ranking = new Ranking(Id, Score);
            rankingList.add(ranking);


        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return rankingList;
}


//Update version 2.0
public int getPlayCount(int level) {
    int result = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT PlayCount FROM UserPlayCount WHERE Level=" + level + ";", null);
        if (c == null) return 0;
        c.moveToNext();
        do {
            result = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PlayCount"));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public void updatePlayCount(int level, int PlayCount) {
    String query = String.format("UPDATE UserPlayCount Set PlayCount = %d WHERE Level = %d", PlayCount, level);
    database.execSQL(query);
}
```

this is my **ContentAdapter**

```
public class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context context;
private boolean isFavorite;
WorldCountryDatabase worldCountryDatabase;
private List<AsiaCountry> item = Collections.emptyList();
private int mLastPosition = -1;
private Listener listener;


public ContentAdapter(Context context, List<AsiaCountry> item) {
    this.context = context;
    this.item = item;

}


public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ContentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    //Defain the view for take layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,
            parent, false);
    Log.d("Adapter", "Loaded");
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    final AsiaCountry asia = item.get(position);

    isFavorite = true;
    holder.titleNameCountry.setText(asia.getName());
    Log.d("TAG", asia.getName());


    Glide.with(context).load(asia.getFlag(context)).into(holder.titleImageCountry);


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(position);

                String nameCountry = holder.titleNameCountry.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsCountry.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", nameCountry);
                Log.d("CONT", nameCountry);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });


    if (position > mLastPosition) {
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY",
                        holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight() * 2, 0));
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "alpha", 0, 1);
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleX", 0.5f, 1);
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "scaleY", 0.5f, 1);


        animatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animatorSet.start();

        mLastPosition = position;
    } else {

        ViewHolder.clear(holder.itemView);
    }


}

private void updateUnFavoriteCountry() {

    AsiaCountry asiaCountry;
    int position = item.size();
    asiaCountry = item.get(position);
    String nameCountry = asiaCountry.getName();
    worldCountryDatabase.QueryData("UPDATE country SET FavoriteCountry = 1 WHERE name =' " + nameCountry);
    worldCountryDatabase.close();
}

private void updateFavoriteCountry() {

    AsiaCountry asiaCountry;
    int position = item.size();
    asiaCountry = item.get(position);
    String nameCountry = asiaCountry.getName();
    worldCountryDatabase.QueryData("UPDATE country SET FavoriteCountry = 0 WHERE name =' " + nameCountry);
    worldCountryDatabase.close();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();
}

public void setFilter(ArrayList<AsiaCountry> arrayList) {

    item.clear();
    item.addAll(arrayList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static interface Listener {
    public void onClick(int position);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView titleImageCountry;
    public TextView titleNameCountry;
    private ImageButton favoriteCountry;
    private ImageButton shareFavoriteCountry;

    // Defian the viewHolder
    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleImageCountry = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
        titleNameCountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleCountry);
        favoriteCountry = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favoriteCountryImage);
        shareFavoriteCountry = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareFavoriteCountry);
    }

    // public static class ViewHolder {

    private static void clear(View itemView) {
        ViewCompat.setAlpha(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.setTranslationY(itemView, 0);
        itemView.setPivotY(itemView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
        ViewCompat.setScaleX(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(itemView, 1);
        ViewCompat.animate(itemView).setInterpolator(null);
        Log.d("Animationg", "Loaded");


    }
}
```

}

I loaded items like below, and when click on like button, must be changed to liked button, and item added to favorite item.[Recylerview items inside fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/325Bc.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], just because it is a good idea and you even get a badge for it. Concerning your problem, I recommend to focus on the database side by making a little toy database in SQLite command line tool and playing with that in pure SQLite syntax. That toy database could also serve as a very nice [mcve] for helping readers understand your question.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your database, **ITEM_TABLE** should have a column **FAVORITE** with an **integer** value (0 == false and 1 == true). When user click on favourite button change FAVORITE value to 1.

Furthermore you should setup a listener for you item, so if item FAVORITE value changes something will happen (button design will changes etc...)

Comment: thanks dear for your response. I change type column to integer. I know process, but I don't know how write code for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

also, you can add another  NEW table (favourites_table) and after action occurred new item will be added or deleted from your table.